# refreshing QTreeView / QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Good Day to All,

Been writing code for years, but still a bit green when it comes to PyQt,
so please forgive my syntactically lacking question(s) ;-)

I'm hacking a derivative of the (famous?) packaged example that
comes with PyQt4 (and Qt), namely "basicsortfiltermodel.pyw"
from "../examples/itemviews" in PyQt4...

I've added a little popup menu (let's call this B.py) that one can launch
from the BasicSort-derivative (let's call this A.py).

I believe I'm correcting adding new data (a new record) to the
QSortFilterProxyModel().  (I think this because I'm not getting
any errors now, after some effort)  But I seem to be unable to get
the QTreeView to refresh.  I've scoured the Qt class docs and
Google'd the heck out of it  (seems like a common question from
the looks of it, lol)..

Now I know this is an ugly hack, but just to try to get it to work
(elegance can come later is my theory)...
At the bottom of A.py, I declared a global "wX",

```
global wX;

[...]
window = Window()
wX = Window()
window.setSourceModel(createMailModel(window))
```

so that when I hit a button later, I could more easily get a hold
of the "parent" value found in the runtime "createMailModel".
From which I get the "model" handle..

```
    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(0, 17, WinX)

    addMail(model, "image",
                           "tabl00",
                            etc
                            etc)
```

Anyways,..I think this is working....
But after adding a new record via addMail(), I can't seem to get
self.proxyModel to refresh itself..

I'm pretty sure this a stupid newbie issue, lol....but could anyone
help shed some light on how to make this work?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have to add new items into your original model not the proxy one. Once items is added proxy model and view will updates themselves accordingly. See if an example below would work for you:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class MainForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainForm, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setMinimumSize(300, 400)

        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.sortModel = QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.sortModel.setSourceModel(self.model)

        parentItem = self.model.invisibleRootItem()
        parentItem.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem("3"))
        parentItem.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem("1"))
        parentItem.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem("4"))
        parentItem.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem("2"))

        self.view = QtGui.QListView(self)
        self.view.setModel(self.sortModel)
        self.view.setGeometry(0, 0, 200, 400) 

        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("add items", self)
        self.button.move(200, 0)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_button_clicked)

        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget())        
        self.layout.addWidget(self.view)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.sortModel.sort(0)

    def on_button_clicked(self):
        parentItem = self.model.invisibleRootItem()
        parentItem.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem("222"))
        parentItem.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem("333"))
        parentItem.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem("444"))

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainForm()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: Yes,it sure does!...Thank you very much, Serge! ;-)